# Load Posts on Click via Ajax into a DIV

Tags: php, posts, ajax, javascript

Is it possible to load a specific amount of posts on click into a DIV via ajax?
I've found a lot of tutorials, but all of them make use of the load-more- / next-page-functionality of a theme.

What I need is, that the initial DIV is empty and the posts are only loaded into the div, if u click a toggle-button.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is simply, yes it is possible. It involves code across JS and PHP and is beyond what I would be able to show in an answer here. However I did a simple Google search for "wordpress load posts with ajax" and this link is the first result. https://wpmudev.com/blog/load-posts-ajax/ I scanned through the tutorial and it appears to be very detailed and I believe it should help you get where you need to be.